# Update UITableViewCell Subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a very simple question that I can't (for the life of me) figure out. I know I'm going to smack myself when I hear the answer.

I have a `UITableView`, and on it, `UITableViewCell` subclasses. Each cell has a UIButton subview.

I need the button on each cell to be disabled if a boolean value is false; the button should be enabled if/when the boolean value changes to true. I will observe KVC. Where should I have the handler for this? In the `UIViewController`? If so, what is the best way to tell the cells that they need to disable/enable the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement the show/hide functionality in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and call `[tableView reloadData]` (or a more specific reload/refresh call) when a change to the boolean value was made.

Comment: +1 Very short and nice answer. It's always easier to change the dataSource and then reload the view binding to it.

Comment: This wouldn't be too expensive?

Comment: It depends on your usage.  If you're changing them all at once, then this is probably the most efficient way.  If you're changing a cell at a time and are worried about efficiency, call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` instead of `reloadData`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches.

1) reloadData (as was suggested earlier)

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"data.boolean"]) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

2) The second is to iterate the visible cells.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"data.boolean"]) {
        for (MyTableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
            cell.button.hidden = !self.data.boolean;
        }
    }
}
```